# Disable center button in MyLocation at Google Map API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I searched a lot on the web, but I haven't found anything which answered my question.
When I enable MyLocation with

> gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)

I automatically get a button to center the map on my current location.
I want to remove it and so I'm asking you how to do this.
I hope somebody of you can help me!

Answer (score 177, accepted):

After calling the following methods on your `GoogleMap` object:

```java
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

you should see the current location indicator (the blue circle), but no control to center the map on that location.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it is 100% what the guy was looking for and the acceptable way to do it.

Comment: When I do this I still get the blue dot or a blue arrow. Disabling the compass does not seem to help.

Comment: @AndrewS: If you want to disable the blue dot you have to set map.setMyLocationEnabled(false). The code from the answer enables the blue dot, but disables the button.

Comment: @Apfelsaft, but then you cannot interact with the location services of Google Maps because the location sublayer has not be initialized.

Comment: This does not take away the blue dot though. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 10):

It's very simple answer ;

```
gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); ==> means "to center the map on my current location"
gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(false); ==> means "NOT to center the map on my current location"
```

[update]

If you want to remove your Location Button on your map, search this below in your code and delete it;

```
public void setMyLocationButtonEnabled(View v) {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }
    // Enables/disables the my location button (this DOES NOT enable/disable the my location
    // dot/chevron on the map). The my location button will never appear if the my location
    // layer is not enabled.
    mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
}

public void setMyLocationLayerEnabled(View v) {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }
    // Enables/disables the my location layer (i.e., the dot/chevron on the map). If enabled, it
    // will also cause the my location button to show (if it is enabled); if disabled, the my
    // location button will never show.
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(((CheckBox) v).isChecked());
}
```

Comment: I only want to disable the button. If I add your statement, my location will never be displayed

Comment: NOT USE "gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)" in your code: delete it.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you don't understand me. I want to show the current location, but not the button to center the map.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/backgroundMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

It effectively removes all the default UI off my maps except for the UI related to markers.
Check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#using_xml_attributes) link for more info.

**EDIT**

Replying to OP's comment, id advise using a custom location algorithm instead of letting the google maps API take over. I've done it before and its not overly painful, i just put a marker on the map to let the user know where he is, and make the marker draggable so the user can refine his position manually.

Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html) link.

Comment: It looks very good, but I can't find the exact statement to remove the center button.

Comment: Any specific reason not to cook up a quick location listener? I know its more work but it pays off in the end. Not judging your decision, just want to see another viewpoint.

Comment: Because I like the drawable of Google's myLocation and people already know what it is.

Comment: Im pretty sure that drawable can be used as a bitmap for a marker, a slight amount of reverse engineering on the maps api jar will be needed though. The markers themselves are the iconic inverted droplets