# How to replace blue dot with my icon on google maps v2 in android?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am trying to replace blue dot (which shown current location on maps) with my own icon on Google maps v2. I have tried below, none worked.

- [Android Maps API v2 Change MyLocation Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826345/android-maps-api-v2-change-mylocation-icon)
- [Maps V2 myLocation blue dot callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047988/maps-v2-mylocation-blue-dot-callback)
- [Disable center button in MyLocation at Google Map API V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376361/disable-center-button-in-mylocation-at-google-map-api-v2)

Should look like this
[image: this]

Below did not work

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.drawable.location_arrow1);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition)
        .title(getIntent().getStringExtra("first_name"))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(b)));
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your current progress?

Comment: I just cleaned up the question, formatting was just.. $#$%$

Comment: @Siddharth truly still waiting for answer....

Comment: You have it below, you just wont code yourself.

Comment: @Siddharth thanks a lot for appreciation!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to stop using [`GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)) and write a bit more code, including [`receiving location updates`](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) on your own and adding `Circle` for accuracy.

Comment: @Siddharth I think it is more like 10-20 lines for the whole thing ;)

Comment: No, you are kidding, last I counted it was 16. Oh!! you are counting the  { }. Bang on man. Btw, still no appreciation from @HemantChandDungriyal.

Comment: This answer assumes far too much knowledge of the Google Maps API.

Comment: I dunno, but honestly "write a bit more code" with a link to an API reference left me on my own to find something more practical.  Is there a tutorial out there?

For my purposes, I wound up using information at: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html, disabling the dot and using location services to get the location.

Comment: @AndrewProck I've just noticed the link to API that was in my answer is now dead (redirecting to package summary). I've updated answer with a more appropriate link. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of the link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: As per @leeyang :- In my experience, it worked successfully
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007271/how-to-delete-blue-dot-in-android-google-map/52007560#52007560

Answer (score 3):

I think you pass your current location to LocationSource to be able to use the my-location button.

You have to do that on your own.
- set to false `gmaps.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);`

- create your own location button
- if you get your current location, set a marker with your icon on that
- if you click on your location button, move the camera and center it to the map

Comment: No he did not, noone has time to go through 3 links. Instead it would be so much better if you just extract the code from your links and explain what you tried and what happened. Seriously!! how is anyone going to understand what answer in these 3 questions you are referring too. Links are discouraged for this exact reason.

Comment: This does not remove the blue dot, is there more?