# Android - Disable MyLocation button on google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am using latest Google Maps API.
My problem goes like this:

I want to remove the MyLocation button (The blue dot/arrow) WITHOUT disabling MyLocation layer.

if I use this code:

```
googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

It doesn't work, unless I add:

```
googleMap().setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

but I want to keep it true. any suggestions?

Comment: did you see this(see john ellis answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376361/disable-center-button-in-mylocation-at-google-map-api-v2

Comment: Do you want to show your own custom marker?

Answer (score 12):

[Google Map Doc says](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/interactivity#my_location_button) You can disable the button from appearing altogether by calling

> UiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(boolean true/false)

Comment: This does not work for me I still get the blue button.

Comment: you can ask new question with your your code.above method valid method by google , you are doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: If I ask a new question the SO crowd will probably mark it as a  duplicate.

Comment: Shows error: "non-static method setMyLocationButtonEnabled(boolean) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: To avoid the last error of "non-static method" just do: mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true/false)

Comment: Is there any way to attach a custom listener to it?

Comment: @Daniele What's your actual requirement ?